# Return rows only if 2 values both exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to return a list of customer names from a purchase summary table but only if the customer has bought 2 definitive items within the 1 transaction.

For example table 'transaction'

```
╔══════════════╦════════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ CustomerName ║  Item  ║ Transaction# ║ Amount ║
╠══════════════╬════════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║ Smith        ║ Hammer ║            1 ║ 50.00  ║
║ Smith        ║ Nail   ║            1 ║ 4.00   ║
║ Smith        ║ Screw  ║            1 ║ 5.00   ║
║ Brown        ║ Nail   ║            2 ║ 4.00   ║
║ Brown        ║ Screw  ║            2 ║ 4.00   ║
║ Jones        ║ Hammer ║            3 ║ 50.00  ║
║ Jones        ║ Screw  ║            3 ║ 4.00   ║
║ Smith        ║ Nail   ║            4 ║ 50.00  ║
║ Smith        ║ Hammer ║            4 ║ 4.00   ║
║ Smith        ║ Screw  ║            5 ║ 5.00   ║
╚══════════════╩════════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

I only want to return customers who have bought a Hammer and a screw in the same transaction. It doesn't matter what other items were bought in the same transaction, I only need the details for the hammer and the screw, and only if both the hammer and screw were present in the same transaction.

So the above only needs to return:

```
╔══════════════╦════════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ CustomerName ║  Item  ║ Transaction# ║ Amount ║
╠══════════════╬════════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║ Smith        ║ Hammer ║            1 ║ 50.00  ║
║ Smith        ║ Screw  ║            1 ║ 5.00   ║
╚══════════════╩════════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

Because only transaction 1 contained both a hammer and a screw in the same transaction.

Comment: Where is transaction 3 in your output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a sub-select to find transactions including both Hammer and Screw:

```
select CustomerName, Item, Transaction#, Amount
from purchase
where Transaction# in (select Transaction# from purchase
                       where Item in ('Hammer', 'Screw')
                       group by Transaction#
                       having count(distinct Item) = 2)

  and  Item in ('Hammer', 'Screw')
```

Remove last row if also Nail row should be returned!

Comment: make sure to put the quote behind screw :D

Comment: also I put the test data in a fiddle and seeing as you completed the answer before I got the chance to even start, you can use it :D http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e468/1 edit: now with proper test data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08f20/1